# Let $p$ and $q$ be distinct primes. List all abelian groups of order $p^3q^2$. For each such group, how many elements are there of order $p$?$pq$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, abelian-groups

Let $p$ and $q$ be distinct primes. List all abelian groups of order $p^3q^2$. For each such group, how many elements are there of order $p$?$pq$?

**No need to list all. Just help on the idea.**

I know that the order of an element is the l.c.m. of the order of the element in each cyclic subgroup (direct product.) Note that there are 6 types of abelian groups that are isomorphic to such a group of order $p^3q^2$.

By Cauchy, there exists an element of order $p$ in $\mathbb{Z}_{p^3}$, so the number of elements of such order ($p$) is $\phi(p)$. Since there is no element in $\mathbb{Z}_{q^2}$ has order $p$, there total number of elements with order $p$ is $\phi(p)\times 1$.

Same idea follows for the rest of the possible abelian groups.

Is the are argument correct?

Comment: You can have a look in dammit and Foote book for this. And suppose group is $Z_p^3 \times Z_q^2 $ use o(ab)=LCM (o(a)o(b)) in these groups..

Comment: but is the above correct or no?

Comment: Hmm yeah nothing look wrong in that